# Is it possible to show KQL query results in an Azure alert?

Tags: azure, email, warnings, alert, kql

I have a KQL query that checks config files on 10 VM's for changes.

I've set up a basic alert that sends us an email if the aforementioned query returns '*any*' results but ideally I could do with the results of the query showing in the email alert.

Is this possible?

Comment: Are you using Kusto (Azure Data Explorer) cluster, Azure Log analytics or something else?

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to run a query and based on that, send yourself and email which includes the query results, you can use Microsoft Flow, and the Kusto connector. Please see an example of how to do that [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/flow-usage#conditional-queries).