Can I include results of a custom query into an Azure Alert Monitor notification?
I'm using an Azure Monitor Alert rule based on a custom KQL query:
SynapseIntegrationPipelineRuns
| where OperationName endswith "- succeeded" or OperationName endswith "- failed"
| summarize
    TotalOperations = count(),
    NumFailed = countif(OperationName endswith "- failed")
    by PipelineName
| project PipelineName, Failed = NumFailed
| where Failed > 0
| order by Failed desc

The rule fires if the total of Failed > 0.
When a notification/email arrives it doesn't contain any specifics about what exactly failed. To have teams immediately see whether they should check their pipelines, I would like to have the PipelineName of the query included in the notification.
Under "Detail" of the Alert, there seems to be an option to add custom properties. Can they be used to achieve my goal? I haven't found any docs suggesting how to reference the query results.


Yes, you can include the results of a custom query into an Azure Alert Monitor notification. You can achieve this by using the "Custom Details" feature in the analytics rule wizard, which allows you to surface event data in the alerts that are constructed from those events, making the event data part of the alert properties.  follow the procedure detailed in the "Surface custom event details in alerts in Microsoft Sentinel" article.

You can select fields in your alert's query output whose contents can be included in the name or description of each instance of the alert. If the selected field has no value in a given instance, the alert details for that instance will revert to the defaults specified in the first page of the wizard.In your case, you can select the  PipelineName  field in your query output and include it in the alert details. This will allow teams to immediately see which pipelines they should check.

What you describe is for Sentinel, not Azure Log alerts

If you are looking for the pipeline failed reason, the KQL query won't display the reason for the failure. We can only include in the email notification what we received in the KQL query output, Like Pipeline name.

Yes, that's what I want to know: how can I include result columns of the KQL query into the email. You're screenshot doesn't help me. It's a screenshot of my original query, so I',m not sure I'm getting what you're trying to say? @VenkatV

We can include the KQL query result in the email using Logic Apps, but it's not possible with a custom KQL query. If you need assistance with Logic Apps, I can provide an answer using the Logic App.

duplicate? https://stackoverflow.com/q/66092512/1747983
